# Как прочитать файл, и парсить строки

Tags: java

Есть файл Developer.txt

```
1,Vasya,Petrov,PHP Developer,{1,2,3},50000.0
2,Vasya,Petrov,PHP Developer,{1,4,6},50000.0
3,Vasya,Petrov,PHP Developer,{1,4,6},50000.0
4,Kostya,Gdonov,JS Developer,{2,3,1},100000.0
```

и файл Skill

```
1,Java
5,Scala
3,Python
4,HTML
2,PHP
```

И есть сущности Developer и Skill 
У Developer есть поля `id,name,lastName,Set<Skill>skills` и.т.д
У Skill поля `id,name`

Пробовал делать так

```
 public Developer read(long id) {
        try {
            // find the file with the developer date
            File devFile = new File(FILE_PATH);
            Scanner devScanner = new Scanner(devFile);
            while (devScanner.hasNext()) {
                Developer developer = new Developer();
                String nextLine = devScanner.nextLine();
                String[] devData = nextLine.split(",");
                developer.setId((Long.parseLong(devData[0])));
                developer.setFirstName(devData[1]);
                developer.setLastName(devData[2]);
                developer.setSpecialty(devData[3]);
                developer.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(devData[4])));
                if (id == developer.getId()) {
                    return developer;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

но возникла проблема, как добавить все что скобках  (id скилов у разработчика), что бы потом по id выводил на экран скилы???

Comment: Задача не сложная, но несколько моментов непонятны...Вы передаете id в параметрах метода и на ходу парсите файл. Чтение текстового документа - достаточно медленная и ресурсозатратная процедура. Делать это каждый раз, когда нужен разработчик по id - совсем плохая идея. Может есть смысл сначала парсить файл, а потом искать все уже в заранее подготовленной коллекции?

Comment: Исходный CSV файл неверно сгенерирован, надо было ставить разделителем полей не запятую, а точку с запятой. Рискну предложить заново сгенерировать текстовый файл - имхо это проще чем городить дурацкий код, который хитро парсит неверный CSV файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       public class Analyzer {

    private static String FILE_PATH_DEV = "Developer.txt";
    private static String FILE_PATH_SKILL = "Skill.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Long, Developer> developers;
        try {
            Map<Long, Skill> skills = readSkills();
            developers = readDev(skills);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Analyzer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return;
        }

        //получаем по ID любого разработчика 
        System.out.println(developers.get(2L));

    }

    public static Map<Long, Developer> readDev(Map<Long, Skill> skillsMap) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner devScanner = new Scanner(new File(FILE_PATH_DEV));
        Map<Long, Developer> developers = new HashMap <>();

        while (devScanner.hasNext()) {
            Developer developer = new Developer();
            String nextLine = devScanner.nextLine();
            String[] devData = nextLine.split(",|}|\\{");
            for (int i = 0; i < devData.length; i++) {
                if (devData[i].isEmpty()) continue;
                switch(i){
                    case 0: developer.setId((Long.parseLong(devData[i]))); continue;
                    case 1: developer.setFirstName(devData[i]); continue;
                    case 2: developer.setLastName(devData[i]); continue;
                    case 3: developer.setSpecialty(devData[i]); continue;
                }
                if (i==devData.length-1) developer.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(devData[i])));
                else {
                    Set<Skill> skills = developer.getSkills();
                    if (skills==null) skills = new HashSet<>();
                    // не знаю, как у вас реализовано создание класса Skill, посему кавычки с названием скила пустые
                    skills.add(skillsMap.get(Long.valueOf(devData[i]))); 
                    developer.setSkills(skills);
                }
            }
            developers.put(developer.getId(), developer);
        }
        return developers;
    }

    public static Map<Long, Skill> readSkills() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner devScanner = new Scanner(new File(FILE_PATH_SKILL));
        Map<Long, Skill> skills = new HashMap <>();

        while (devScanner.hasNext()) {
            Skill skill = new Skill();
            String nextLine = devScanner.nextLine();
            String[] devData = nextLine.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < devData.length; i++) {
                if (devData[i].isEmpty()) continue;
                switch(i){
                    case 0: skill.setId((Long.parseLong(devData[i]))); continue;
                    case 1: skill.setName(devData[i]); break;
                }

            }
            skills.put(skill.getId(), skill);
        }
        return skills;
    }

}
```

Comment: получается чтобы достать name Skill надо парсить файл Skill.txt?

Comment: А я откуда знаю? Приложение пишите вы. Если у вас информация о скилах хранится в текстовом файле, то , разумеется, его тоже надо парсить. Делайте это аналогичным способом, т.е. создавайте объекты, складывайте в коллекцию. Потом по айдишнику вы легко получите нужный экземпляр класса, который сможете добавить в вышенаписанный код

Comment: код подправил, должен работать... ну, если что непонятно, пишите

Comment: спасибо большое!!! я уже все написал, поздно сюда зашел чтобы глянуть.

Comment: пользуйтесь на здоровье)))